# Specifying Input Layouts in Regional Settings XML (Unattended)

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, language, xml, regional-settings

I'm automating regional and languages settings, and part of my XML file is:

```
<gs:InputPreferences>
  <gs:InputLanguageID Action="remove" ID="0809:00000809"/> <!-- This removes en-GB -->
  <gs:InputLanguageID Action="add" ID="0c01:00000401" /> <!-- This adds ar-EG -->
</gs:InputPreferences>
```

I found the list of language codes and input profiles here https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/appendix/OSLangCodes.htm  and here 
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/default-input-locales-for-windows-language-packs

The code doesn't work fine. It adds the language profile itself, however, it doesn't add the keyboard layout (e.g. Arabic 101) so the profile is useless until I go and add the layout manually. Is there anyway to fix this?

Comment: `<gs:InputLanguageID Action="add" ID="0c01:00000401" Default="true"/>` could work?

Comment: unfortunately it doesnt. still the same behaviour